# testing Angular directive scope with jQuery loaded

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

When I have an Angular directive that uses a controller I've been able to access the directive's scope in my tests by doing this:

```
element = angular.element('<my-directive></my-directive>');
element = $compile(element)($rootScope);
$rootScope.$digest();

scope = element.scope();
```

That enables me to set/get scope properties and directly call functions defined by the directive's controller.

However, as soon as I introduced jQuery to the project (required by another dependency I want to use) this stopped working. Specifically in the test `element.scope()` is returning `undefined`. Using dev tools I can see that this is not the case when the app is running for real – i.e. I can do `$('.blah').scope()` and get back a non-`undefined` value.

Anyone got an idea why this wouldn't work? I've added jQuery to my *karma.conf.js* (I'm using the Yeoman Angular generator) in the same order as it's included in the HTML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I'm running my tests in PhantomJS and was pulling in jQuery 2.0.3. Downgrading to jQuery 1.10.2 made everything work again. I'm kind of surprised that PhantomJS would have a compatibility issue but that seems to have been the problem.